# windows 7 no internet access

Tags: windows-7, networking

Just did a fresh install of Windows 7, and the network and sharing center says no internet access. Disabling and enabling the adapter seems to fix the issue temporarily, but the internet stops working shortly after. I have installed the latest NIC drivers and have installed all Windows updates. I have also tried manually setting the ip/gateway/dns and running netsh int ip reset in an elevated command prompt.

I am running Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit with a wired connection.

I have searched for hours, but have found no working solutions. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What is the network card ?

Comment: It's a generic 10/100/1000 card. It works fine under XP and Ubuntu.

Comment: This sounds very odd indeed. Have you managed to get the latest Windows Updates?

Comment: All of the latest updates are installed.

Comment: What does 'route print' and 'ipconfig /all' show when the machine is connected and disconnected?

Answer (score 0):

Have you performed ping tests, using the "ping" utility to ping some known site (www.google.com). This will show you the ping times of your connection.

I've had the situation where I had very high (bad) ping times (>1000 ms). When this occurs, the computer is still technically connected to the Internet, but one can't view any webpages, because DNS resolution times out. This means that the computer will show that it IS connected to the Internet.

Sometime afterwards, the ping increases to greater than a critical time and the computer finally registers the connection as unavailable.

This type of issue is usually tied to a bad router, or a line fault of the telephone company.